# Running python code over a lond period of time

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi

I want to run a python code continually over a long period of time like 2/3 Months without checking on it.

Regarding the code, it requests data from a plataform using their api,processes it and sends a POST to make changes on my account on the plataform (also it runs each 15/30 minutes).

I was thinking using a server (google cloud) or a Raspberry Pi but i dont have experience in using any of them so my questions is as follows.

**TLDR of questions**:

-is google server free tier enough for what i want?
-Which raspberry pie should i get/Which microcomputer should i get?
-any other ideas besides these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider Compute Engine that you can configure and run your Python code on. However, you are in charge of installing Python and its necessary dependencies on the VM to run your code.

A suitable product to also consider is [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions#section-4) which is a serverless compute platform that allows you to run event-driven code without worrying about server management. It automatically scales based on the incoming traffic, ensuring that your code can handle the load efficiently. Additionally, you only pay for the compute resources used during the execution of your function.

Consider factors like function timeouts, memory requirements, and any necessary dependencies when designing and deploying your code as a Cloud Function

The free tier on GCP includes a limited amount of usage that can be utilized for running your code without incurring additional costs.
As the free tier has certain limitations on the number of CPUs, memory, and network egress that you can consume. Also, be aware that the free tier has time limits on VM usage, so make sure to manage your VM instances accordingly.

Check out this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#free-tier-usage-limits) for the free tier inclusions for different products

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple products on Google Cloud.

I would suggest using one of their serverless offerings. I recommend serverless so that you only focus on your code and don't have to worry about spinning up a virtual machine, configuring it and maintaining it.

For their serverless offering, I think you should look at [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) (GAE) and [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) (i.e. choose between one of them). If you're familiar with or prefer containers, then go with Cloud Run else use GAE.

Since you need to run your code on a regular schedule, you'll also need [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) or [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview) which allows you to set a schedule for invoking or making a call to the url of your app hosted on GAE or Cloud Run.

Difference between Scheduler and Tasks is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-tasks-sched)